# Are there exact conditional tests for testing system of inequalities of Bernoulli means?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bernoulli-distribution, exact-test

I have two independent Bernoulli samples: $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{n_1}$, $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{n_2}$, $X_i \overset{iid}{\sim} Bern(p_1), Y_i \overset{iid}{\sim} Bern(p_2)$. I need to test:

$$H_0: p_1 \ge p_2 \ge 1/2\ \text{ vs   }\\ H_1: \text{ not } H_0.$$

Importantly, I cannot rely on asymptotics since the sample sizes are small, so I need a test that would control size for any sample size.

I know that to test $p_1 \ge p_2$ I can use the Fisher's exact conditional test, but in my case I have another inequality $p_2 \ge 1/2$, so the test must be modified somehow.

Another possibility would be to exploit the knowledge of distribution and derive the exact distribution of whatever test statistics I use. However, it will most likely depend on the unknown $p_1, p_2$, so I am thinking to use the "least favorable configuration" to compute critical values. It seems intuitively that this least favorable configuration must be $p_1=p_2=1/2$, in which case I can easily compute critical values from this distribution via simulations. However I failed to find any formal argument that this configuration is indeed the least favorable.

I would greatly appreciate any help and references pertaining to such a testing problem.